# Type of vs Types of, kind of vs kinds of

Tags: questions

I found a line on a page where I got,
**What type of books do you need?** 
I think **what types or kinds of books do you need?** is more appropriate.
I would like to know the real use of them. If I am not wrong **type of follows countable one and noun has to be singular**. On the other hand **types of follow uncountable one and noun has to be plural**.
Could someone help me out with this issue?
Please give some example also.